# ElasticSearch aggregations per index

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to be able to be able to get back from ElasticSearch just the number of hits per index (not the actual hits). I thought I might be able to do this through aggregation but can't figure out how. For example I would like something like

```
{
.....
  "aggregations" : {
    "indexes" : {
      "buckets" : [ {
        "key" : "index1",
        "doc_count" : 20
      }, {
        "key" : "index2",
        "doc_count" : 5
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

I have been able to get hits per type across all indexes with

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "types" : {
      "terms": { "field":"_type" }
    }
  }
}
```

but when I try the same with the _index field I get nothing. Is there any way to achieve this through aggregation or some other means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the `_index` field is not stored with your indexed documents. However, you can enable it by updating your mapping similar to the example shown below from the [_index Elasticsearch Reference](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index-field.html):

```
 {
     "tweet" : {
         "_index" : { "enabled" : true }
      }
 }
```

Once you have done this for all indexes/types, your aggregation on the `_index` field will return your expected results.

Comment: This might not work yet with aggregations due to [#5848](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/5848), while it works with facets.